# Check if php mysql query result column is empty

Tags: php

I'm printing out a table with 27 cols from a database, so its obvious that it'll be aesthetically displeasing if 27 cols were visible on my screen. so this is one of the conditions i've been using to see if a particular col is empty, if it is empty then the table header will not be printed and if that isnt printed another if isset condition will not print the table data. But it isn't working out as planned. These are the variations i've tried and none of them are working P.S. $result = number of rows being returned by the query.

```
$i = 1;
while ($i <= $result)

    {
        if (!empty($array['Others'][$i]))
            {

                $others = print "<th>Others</th>";
                break;
            }
        $i++;
    }


$i = 0;
    while ($i <= $result)
    {
        $emptyothers = !empty($array['Others'][$i]);

        if ($emptyothers == '1')
            {

                $others= print "<th>Others</th>";
                break;
            }
        $i++;
    }
```

Comment: Can we have the code that sets this up?  I'm not sure where $array comes from.

Comment: You are starting 1st While loop for header from $i = 1 , while other data loop from $i = 0 ? Does that make any sense in code ? I assume it should be reset to 1 not to 0

Answer (score 5):

Your code should be like this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
    //your code...
} else {
    print 'is empty';
}
```

Comment: No see i am actually checking if each column in my query result is empty so i cannot check if num_rows > 0, i have to check if each sub element is empty which is why you see $array['Others'][$i], because that is how i imagine sub elements are specified.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use `array_key_exists()`?

```
foreach($row in $result) {
    if(array_key_exists('Others', $row)) {
        if(!empty($row['Others']) {
            print "<th>Others</th>";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nope this wont work as well.....it would be really appreciated if you guys can tell me where my code is going wrong and how should i go about fixing it. thanks!